# How to get the ID of the snapshot in cloud functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using cloud functions to trig when a new document is added to the firestore but I couldn't find online how to get the ID of this document.

this is my code :

```
    exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.firestore
  .document(`users/{user}`)
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

      const email = snap.data().userEmail; // The email of the user.
      const displayName = snap.data().userName; // The display name of the user.

  return sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName);
  });
```

I need to get the Id from "snap" how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can access particular fields as you would with any JS property, here's the link to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#event_triggers).